# Is it possible to rename the Areas folder?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

is it possible to rename Areas folder? Or to extend the AreaRegistration.cs to look for a custom folder?

what i need to do to rename Areas folder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to modify the [AreaMasterLocationFormats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.virtualpathproviderviewengine.areamasterlocationformats.aspx) property of WebFormsViewEngine, as well as the related AreaPartialViewLocationFormats and AreaViewLocationFormats. If you are using a different View Engine then you will have to modify it appropriately.

You can grab the View Engine instance from [ViewEngines.Engines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.viewengines.engines.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.
They are just like folders. You have to route it accordingly.